# Неправильное отображение новостей в битриксе

Tags: php, битрикс, веб-сервер, администрирование, настройка

Установил 1с битрикс. При переходе по пунктам Рабочий стол -> Контент -> Новости получал следующие окна

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как добиться правильного отображения.

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что отображение неправильное?

Comment: Смотрите в панели разработчика почему не грузятся файлы джаваскриптов.

Comment: @u_mulder Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden) script.min.js:1

Comment: @ArchDemon посмотрите на неоформленную должным образом таблицу (со столбцами Название, Активность, Сорт., Дата изм. и ID) и ссылки с текстом Выбрать все

Comment: попробуйте проверить есть ли файл на самом деле (на котором ошибка). Проверьте права на папке и файл где лежат (что бы понять почему вам запрещён доступ) (может даже в папке быть файлик .access битриксовый какой нить ), можете отдельно дёрнуть именно его в браузере. Надо идти по ошибкам в консоли браузере, попробовать сбросить кеш. Маловероятно но антивирус вашего компьютера может блокировать какие нибудь js.

Answer (score 1):

Так проверьте права на папке и файл. Вам просто запрещён доступ к ним. Можете попробовать сбросить кеш.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]