# Полная очистка кэша bitrix и windows

Tags: битрикс, кэширование, обновление

В связи с вопросом [Неправильное отображение новостей в битриксе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1097642/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b5) возникло ощущение, что при каждом новом открытии страницы новостей, страница загружается из кэша . Как очистить кэш битрикса и виндовса?

Answer (score 0):

Вы просто закидали stackoverflow одним вопросом и подвопросами...

**Ответ на вопрос:**

Чтобы сбросить кеш у Битрикса "в ноль на горячую", так сказать, в папке сайта есть папка bitrix, в ней удалите папки: `cache`, `html_pages`, `managed_cache`, `stack_cache`. Если средствами самого битрикса, то `настроки - настройки продукта - автокеширование - очистка файлов кеша`

Сброс *кеша Windows* вам вообще зачем? Может быть имелось в виду *кеш браузера*? Тогда в меню браузера ищите. В Chrome это `настройки - очистить историю`.

**Мысли вслух:**

Но вам все это не поможет, у Вас либо какой-нибудь "пиратский Битрикс", либо установка прошла с ошибками, либо (скорее всего) у Вас как-то криво работает локальный веб-сервер, из-за этого чудит с доступами к файлам, например...

Перед установкой Битрикс тест среды проходили?

Скачайте бесплатный VirtualBox или VMWare Player, поставьте там [Виртуальную машину Битрикс](https://www.1c-bitrix.ru/download/vmbitrix.php) и спокойно работайте